# How to write an excel function in VBA that has an input as an array?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a function that measures the size of a user-defined array (for example, the input on this is a 2x2 array in excel, each cell contains a "1" [Excel Formula {=RRR(A1:B2)} - see below]) so I can build a function around that information.

Everything else in my function works but this particular section. The error message is "Expected Array". Apparently "rng" is not being input as an array. (See code below)

```
Public Function RRR(rng As Range)

RRR = UBound(rng, 1)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you need first to transform the range into an array, something like

```vb
Dim array1() As Variant 
array1 = rng.Value
RRR = UBound(array1, 1)
```

Comment: This works, thank you. I'm new to Excel VBA and it's a bit frustrating to get data into the right format for other bits of the code to work.

Comment: @Corrado Barbero: Be careful, if you use `rng.Value` and `rng` is a single cell, the result is not an array and the `Ubound` will throw a runtime error

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with a range and want to know the number of rows or columns, simply use
`rng.Rows.Count` and `rng.Columns.Count`.

It's not necessary to convert the content of the range first into an array - and it will fail if the range contains only one cell (because in that case the result of the `Value`-function is a scalar and not an array).